# how do i exactly match in dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas

in below the picture I like exactly match such as bitcoin match to bitcoin,
but right now bitcoin match to anything that contains "bitcoin"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YuWe.png)

Comment: Why use `match` if you're looking for an exact string? Use `==`. Please don't post external screenshots of things important to your question, you should make your question self-contained

Comment: Tree, are looking for that `bitcoin` in a particular column?

Comment: Hi roganjosh, thank you so much, it 's work!!. i wll be carful for my posting next time :)

Comment: Hi pygo, I like to filter the row that label "bitcoin" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see your DataFrame, you have a particulat column that has the string `bitcoin` so better would be match it based on column like below..

Just a example set..

```
>>> df
   vals             ids
0     1         bitcoin
1     2        bbitcoin
2     3         bitcoin
3     4  anotherbitcoin
```

Result:

```
>>> df[df.ids == "bitcoin" ]
   vals      ids
0     1  bitcoin
2     3  bitcoin
```

OR

```
>>> df[df['ids'] == 'bitcoin']
   vals      ids
0     1  bitcoin
2     3  bitcoin
```

another..

```
>>> print(df[df['ids'].str.strip()=="bitcoin"])
   vals      ids
0     1  bitcoin
2     3  bitcoin
```

Even can call the query method with a boolean expression. This expression is based on the column names

```
# df.query('ids == "bitcoin"')
```

In case you are comparing multiple columns basd on the values you want..

```
>>> df[(df['ids'] == 'bitcoin') & (df['vals'] == 3)]
   vals      ids
2     3  bitcoin
```